# Execute shell script using google cloud dataflow job

Tags: shell, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to execute shell script placed in a bucket using dataflow job. I can execute gsutil commands using this job using Direct Runner :

```
String[] cmdline = { "cmd.exe", "/c", "gsutil ls gs://Bucketname" };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdline); 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
           String line = null;
           while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
           {
              System.out.println(line);
           }
```

Note : I will use dataflow runner to execute the script because i am using windows machine.

Comment: Are you trying to run this from within a ParDo? Is this failing? If so, what error are you seeing? What does your pipeline look like?

Comment: If i write String command = "bash shellDataflow.sh"; Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);. I get error message as " execption occured Cannot run program "bash": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified" . Error is like this because above program is invoking my windows system's command line instance . Is there any way to connect to cloud console enviroment through java code so that i can run my shell in that enviroment using my dataflow job.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this. It runs in my case. You have to deploy the code in cloud as a `.jar` or a maven project. The path `/home/*/test.sh` is in the cloud console.

```
String[] cmd = {"sh",  "/home/akash/test.sh", "/home/akash/"};
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```